# Image of product is not coming in cart.info method of soap api

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, soap-api-v2

I need to show small image of product on cart page.Cart info is not giving any information for image of product.
So I have tried overriding cart.info method.

My config.xml(/etc/config.xml) is like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
<modules>
    <Customsoapcart_Checkoutsoap>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Customsoapcart_Checkoutsoap>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <customsoapcart_checkoutsoap>
            <class>Customsoapcart_Checkoutsoap_Model</class>
        </customsoapcart_checkoutsoap>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <cart_product_api_v2>Customsoapcart_Checkoutsoap_Model_Checkout_Cart_Product_Api_V2</cart_product_api_v2>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <customsoapcart_checkoutsoap>
            <class>Customsoapcart_Checkoutsoap_Helper</class>
        </customsoapcart_checkoutsoap>
    </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

My wsdl.xml(/etc/wsdl.xml) is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
<types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <complexType name="shoppingCartProductEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="small_image" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>

    </schema>
</types>
</definitions>
```

My V2.php file
(/namespacename/modulename/Model/Checkout/Cart/Product/Api/V2.php) is like:

```
<?php
class Customsoapcart_Checkoutsoap_Model_Checkout_Cart_Product_Api_V2 extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Product_Api_V2
{
/**
* Retrieve full order information
*
* @param string $orderIncrementId
*
* @return array
*/

public function items($quoteId, $store = null)
{
$productsResult = parent::items($quoteId, $store = null);
$productsResult['image']='image';
    return $productsResult;
}
}
```

Now when I call my web service in my script:

```
 $proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl', array('trace' => 1, 'cache_wsdl' => 0)); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('username', 'apikey'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->shoppingCartInfo($sessionId, '320');
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

I am not getting extra field image in the result.
I think something is wrong with wsdl.xml which I am missing something in wsdl.xml but cant able to figure out it.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out another way to solve the problem. I have made custom module in rest api for giving cart information.Web service will take quote_id as parameter and it will return cart information in reponse.

For example: My web service request is http://magentohost/api/rest/cartcollection/:cart_id

```
$cartId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cart_id');
    $quoteCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection();
    $quoteCollection->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $cartId);
```

Then it will fetch information from sales/quote_item table and return the collection of quote.